# $4$ counters, $16$ boxes, probability that $2$ will be in the same box

Tags: probability

I am a GCSE student and am doing additional maths.

My question is if I have $16$ boxes and at random $4$ counters are put into these boxes, there is a max of $2$ counters per box, what is the probability that there will be:

a) one or more boxes that will have $2$ counters in it?

b) only one box with two counters in it?

This isn't a paper or anything, I'm just curious as to how you would do it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: Count the number of ways to distribute the counters between boxes under your constraint. Then count the number of ways you can have one/two boxes with two counters. Then divide.

Answer (score 1):

Under your constraints, there are only three possibilities:

- Four boxes each have one counter;
- Two boxes each have two counters;
- Two boxes have one counter each, and one box has two counters.

The number of possibilities are, respectively, $\binom{16}{4}, \binom{16}{2},\text{ and } \binom{16}{2}\binom{14}{1}$.

Take it from here.

**EDIT**

I am assuming that the counters are indistinguishable, but the boxes are distinct.

Comment: Thanks but I'm struggling with understanding what the numbers in the bracket means. Sorry if I am being stupid but I have no clue what the brackets and numbers are. Thanks.